# The theory tag may be redundant

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[theory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/theory) has 15 questions. Some are low quality but out of scope. Its also a classic meta-tag, and considering our close reasons contain a mention of *practical* problems, I propose we nuke this

Comment: *"Some are low quality but out of scope"* - Is that theory or fact? :P. Nah I agree, burn it